# Slice or downsize (resize) image for neural networks

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, dataset, image-segmentation, training-data

Given a dataset of images with very big resolution, 8000x6000, which is the best method to train a neural network? For image segmentation and not only.

As the title says, should I slice them for 800x600 each patch of image or should I resize the whole image to 800x600?

In the first case I'd lose the content aware and in second case I'd lose a lot of details but it will be content aware of the full image.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Resizing is a better option. Often your neural network does not require all the details from a super high resolution, and a smaller resolution suffices. The content of the image, on the other hand, is important and it may become problematic depending on what part of the image you crop it.

Comment: Wouldn't 90% of details be lost if I resize the whole image? On the other hand, I have a few of those super high resolution and I though that if I crop them and then resize I'd get more images to train.

Comment: Sure, you can crop and resize them to have more images to train, but that will depend on whether one image has more than one interesting object that you care about. For example, if you have an image with one object and the rest is meaningless background, it doesn't make sense to crop it into multiple parts.

And no, 90% of the details will not be lost if you resize the whole image. A good network will try to understand the image as a whole and how the different parts fit together to form an object etc. You still maintain the semantic representation of the image when it is resized.